# Programmatically set the background of a button to be an image

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, imagesource

how can I programmatically set the background of a button to be an image?
I know how to do it in XAML, but in code, I keep getting stuck, I tried

```
Button.Background = new ImageBrush{ ImageSource = "source" };
```

but then I get the error that string cannot be converted to ImageSource.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Try:
Button.Background = new ImageBrush{ ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgPath, UriKind.Relative)) };
```

Comment: Thx =3 I already found an answer though:
Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = ( ImageSource ) new ImageSourceConverter( ).ConvertFromString( "source" ) }

Comment: +1 Note: if the image is from internet then we have to use Absolute.